# ethernet interping issue, Im able to ping to both eth0 and eth1 from eth0 itself. why?

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, embedded

In one of the projects, we are using the **MYC-Y7Z020-4E512D-766-I SOM** module with Linux **kernel 4.1.4**. Here we wanted to use 2 ethernet ports eth0 and eth1 our requirement is to set the IP of eth0 and eth1 as 172.20.0.200/21 (255.255.248.0) and 172.20.0.201/21 (255.255.248.0) respectively.

After setting both ports to the required IP and performing the ping test I'm able to ping both eth0 and eth1 from the eth0 port connected to a laptop with the IP (172.20.0.150/21), and when I try to ping eth1 from the eth1 port connected and disconnecting eth0 port I'm not able to ping any of the port eth1 or eth0.

Issue: **Here able to ping both ports using the eth0 port only**.

so changed the subnet mask of both eth0 and eth1 to /24 (255.255.255.0) and tested with the same scenario. then I got the same result. pinging both ports with eth0 itself.

Then I set both ports for **different IP series with the same subnet mask** eth0 IP 172.20.0.200/21 (255.255.248.0) and eth1 IP 172.20.1.201/21 (255.255.248.0) and performed a ping test where I observed there was **no inter pinging issue**, I was able to ping 1 to 1. I was able to ping to eth0 only by connecting the laptop to the eth0 port and eth1 only by connecting to the eth1 port.

hear is the how my `/etc/network/interfaces` file looks like

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 172.20.0.74
    netmask 255.255.248.0
    gateway 172.20.0.10

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
        address 172.20.8.201
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 172.20.8.10
```

how to overcome this ping issue when both ports are in the same IP series.

Answer (score 2):

Don't put both interfaces into the same subnet. If you want resilience then look at bonding (this assigns one IP address but uses both ports).

(You can of course assign multiple IP addresses to the same interface. You can also assign two interfaces into the same subnet as you are doing, but don't expect it to work as a textbook model.)

Comment: any reference will help me a lot what i need to go through for bonding IP ........

Comment: @Rajesh https://wiki.debian.org/Bonding